# How can I download the Cassini webserver source code?

Tags: asp.net, cassini

How can I download the Cassini webserver source code?

MSDN says that it's available at http://www.asp.net/Projects/Cassini/Download.

But this Link just redirects me to a useless archive website. There was also an similar question on Stack Overflow, but it seems that all answers are obsolete now because not a single link is working.

Comment: Searching the web for "cassini Source" shows interesting hits.

Comment: Yes "interesting" but not useful. ;-)

Comment: Hit 1: [cassini - Microsoft's open source, portable and redistributable web server on .NET 4.0 - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/cassini/), hit 2: [CassiniDev - Cassini 3.5/4.0 Developers Edition - Home](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/). Please elaborate "not useful".

Comment: @CodeCaster - these are all forks. It's difficult to find the original one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest public version available I know of was available at *[Cassini for Framework 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx)*, but the link is dead (all links pointing to Dmitry Robsman's blog are dead in fact, and he was Cassini author I believe).

However if you know the file was named Cassini-v35.zip, you can now find it here: https://larytet-master.googlecode.com/files/Cassini-v35.zip for example.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why Microsoft is unable to host such a tiny file.
BTW: For other users, here is a non-direktlink:
https://code.google.com/p/larytet-master/downloads/detail?name=Cassini-v35.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: `code.google.com`, `larytet-master.googlecode.com`, and `googlecode.com` are all broken now (404 for the last two). [Google Code closed down in 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Developers#Google_Code).